# How to comunicate python-mysql and js with ajax?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, apache

Hello I'm working in a simple app with python 3.6 in apache server with xampp and i don't comunicate the information between the js code and python with database mysql..

this is my code:

ajax2.py

```
#!C:\users\SRT\Local Settings\Application Data\Programs\Python\Python36\python
import sys
import json
import cgi
import mysql.connector
import json

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host = "localhost",
    user = "root",
    passwd = "",
    database = "mydatabase"
) 

fs = cgi.FieldStorage()

sys.stdout.write("Content-Type: application/json")

sys.stdout.write("\n")
sys.stdout.write("\n")
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

sql = "SELECT * from users WHERE name = %s"

result = {}
result['success'] = True
result['message'] = "The command Completed Successfully"
result['keys'] = ",".join(fs.keys())

user = fs.getvalue("name")  #this is correct ???

mycursor.execute(sql,user)
myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

result['data'] = myresult

sys.stdout.write(json.dumps(result,indent=1))
sys.stdout.write("\n")

sys.stdout.close()
```

And my javascrip is:

main.js

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
     $("#myButton").click(myFunction);

});

function myFunction()
{

$.ajax({
    url: "ajax2.py",
    type: "post",
    datatype: "data",
    data: {name: $("#inputName").val(), pass: $("#inputPassword").val()},
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response.message);
        console.log(response.keys);
        console.log(response.data);
    }
 });
}
```

in Html only have input with id = "inputName", input with id = "inputPassword" and a button with id = "myButton"

the database in mysql has a table user with name varchar, password varchar and id int

Can you help me??

I would like know how to send data from js ajax to python use this infprmation for a consult and send the result to ajax and use in Javascript.

Comment: The best way to do it using Flask or Django by creating one simple app.

Comment: I don't use a framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is use a follow form:

```
sql = "SELECT * from users WHERE name ='{}' and password = '{}'".format(fs['name'].value, fs['pass'].value)
```

When I execute the mysql query i'ts fine!